# What are the common Income Tax deduction for salary earned in Saudi Arabia

Tags: taxes, india, salary, deduction, saudi-arabia

I have left for Saudi Arabia on 7 November 13 , I am a government employee in Saudi Arabia . My salary is deposited in Saudi bank account , will I have to pay tax on 1,000,000 rupees amount which I have send before 31 March 13.

Comment: as i have stayed more than 182 days , i will not be considered as   NRI ,thus tax deduction will be under which categories  .

Comment: can you elaborate on the Rs 1,000,000/- where was this earned, where was this transferred from and to, ie did you move it from India to Saudi or from Saudi to India? And did you earn this in India or Saudi?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have earned the income in Saudi and have transferred Rs 1,000,000 to India and will you have to pay any tax on these funds transferred to India.

As you have stayed for more than 182 days in India for Financial year 2013-2014, you are a tax resident in India. India taxes on Global Income. So for the Financial Year April 2013 till 7-Nov-2013 your salary and income in India needs to be added along with the Salary/Income you earned in Saudi from 7-Nov-2013 till 31-Mar-2014.

It is irrelevant whether you have transferred the funds to India or NOT. The tax liability does not change. Once you have arrived total tax liability, you can claim tax benefit to the extent of taxes paid in Saudi under Section 90. Essentially India has Dual Tax Avoidance Treaty and you can claim benefit.

More details are here at [Income tax](http://law.incometaxindia.gov.in/DIT/File_opener.aspx?fn=http://law.incometaxindia.gov.in/Directtaxlaws/cbdt/dta/A1_saudi_arabia.htm)

Its best to consult a CA would can advice you better.